# Threaded function not behaving as intended kivy

Tags: python, multithreading, kivy, python-multithreading

Im successfully threaded a function, everything else is behaving as intended but the line which adds the string to the adapter is not adding even though the line after that is working successfully. The line is `self.notificationslist.adapter.data.extend([value])`. im not receiving any errors which is very inconvenient cause i cant pinpoint whats wrong. I think it has something to do with Kivy. Any aid to anything i'm doing wrong, i would appreciate it.

Below is my code

```
class Notifications(Screen):

    def processinformation(self):
        app = App.get_running_app()
        session = requests.Session()
        self.notif_stream = session.get("**************************************************" + app.displayname + "/.json", stream=True)
        for line in self.notif_stream.iter_lines():
            if line:
                print(json.loads(line))
                newline = ast.literal_eval(line.decode('utf-8'))
                for key, thevalue in newline.items():
                    for key, value in thevalue.items():
                        self.notif = session.get("****************************************************" + app.displayname + "/" + key + "/" + "notification" + "/.json")                          
                        self.notificationslist.adapter.data.extend([value])
                        print(True)


    def callthread(self):
        threading.Thread(target=self.processinformation).start()

thenotif = Notifications()
thethread = thenotif.callthread()
```

Comment: how exactly it's not working? any error message?

Comment: `callthread()` doesn't return anything so `None` will be assigned to `thethread`. What  line line adds the string to the adapter? Your description is unclear and lacks sufficient details for anyone to really help you.

Comment: As @martineau said, thethread will be always None. What do you want as return? If you want "The Thread" I think you have to get something like:

__return threading.Thread(target=self.processinformation).start()__

Comment: Everything is working except  `self.notificationslist.adapter.data.extend([value])` line @TiagoGomes @martineau

Comment: If that failing line affects the GUI, then it must be executed on the main thread. If you run `processinformation()` on the main thread without using threading and it works (even if the GUI is frozen while it runs), then that is the problem. If that is the problem, then that specific line must be run on the main thread, which you can do using `Clock.schedule_once()`.

Comment: @JohnAnderson tried your way but still doesn’t work. Read in their documentation that you can’t do OpenGL graphics related in a thread. Any possible way I can go about it

Comment: Please expand your question to include a [mcve] showing what you have tried.

Comment: self.notificationslist.adapter.data is a list?
value is not empty?

The way you are asking makes it hard to reproduce the error...